# Angular Directive ViewContainerRef Test Mock

Tags: angular, jasmine

Given a directive used for [Dynamic Component Loading](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) with [ViewContainerRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef) injected:

```
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[fooHost]'
})
export class FooDirective {
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {}
}
```

How would you inject an instance or mock of `ViewContainerRef` in a unit test:

```
import { FooDirective } from './foo.directive';

describe('FooDirective', () => {
  it('should create an instance', () => {
    const directive = new FooDirective();
    expect(directive).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

This most basic test fails due to the following error:

> An argument for 'viewContainerRef' was not provided.

The [testing guide](https://angular.io/guide/testing) does not cover this nor does there appear to be any testing module specifically for creating an instance of `ViewContainerRef`.

Is this is simple as creating a stub `@Component` with `TestBed.createComponent` and passing either the fixture or component instance as `ViewContainerRef`?

```
import { FooDirective } from './foo.directive';
import { ViewContainerRef, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';

@Component({ selector: 'app-stub', template: '' })
class StubComponent {}

describe('LightboxDirective', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({ declarations: [StubComponent] }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create an instance', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(StubComponent);
    const component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;

    const directive = new FooDirective(component);
    expect(directive).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

If that is the case, what should be passed as `ViewContainerRef`, the `fixture.debugElement.componentInstance` or `fixture.debugElement.nativeElement` or something else?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever tried the simplest form for your basic testing? const directive = new FooDirective(null,null); For further problems in this direction I haven't found anything either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ViewContainerRef` is an abstract class that is imported from `@angular/core`. Because it is an *abstract* class, it cannot be directly instantiated. However, in your test class, you can simply create a new class which `extends` the ViewContainerRef, and implements all of the required methods. Then, you can simply instantiate a new instance of the TestViewContainerRef and pass it into your FooDirective constructor in your test/spec. As such:

```
// create the test class
class TestViewContainerRef extends ViewContainerRef {
  get element(): import("@angular/core").ElementRef<any> {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
  get injector(): import("@angular/core").Injector {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
  get parentInjector(): import("@angular/core").Injector {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
  clear(): void {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
  get(index: number): import("@angular/core").ViewRef {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
  get length(): number {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
  createEmbeddedView<C>(templateRef: import("@angular/core").TemplateRef<C>, context?: C, index?: number): import("@angular/core").EmbeddedViewRef<C> {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
  createComponent<C>(componentFactory: import("@angular/core").ComponentFactory<C>, index?: number, injector?: import("@angular/core").Injector, projectableNodes?: any[][], ngModule?: import("@angular/core").NgModuleRef<any>): import("@angular/core").ComponentRef<C> {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
  insert(viewRef: import("@angular/core").ViewRef, index?: number): import("@angular/core").ViewRef {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
  move(viewRef: import("@angular/core").ViewRef, currentIndex: number): import("@angular/core").ViewRef {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
  indexOf(viewRef: import("@angular/core").ViewRef): number {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
  remove(index?: number): void {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
  detach(index?: number): import("@angular/core").ViewRef {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }

}
```

Hint: I am using VS Code on a Mac. When I create the class stub `class TestViewContainerRef extends ViewContainerRef { }`, Code gives me a very helpful code hint to implement all abstract methods. I used that to automatically generate the code above. Other IDEs may offer similar functionality to help the process go smoother. You may be able to copy/paste the code here to use in your test/spec class. However, Angular may choose to change the interface for the ViewContainerRef abstract class at any time, so if you do copy this code above, be aware that you do so at your own peril.

Here's an example of how I used it to get my Angular tests to pass:

```
import { ModalHostDirective } from './modal-host.directive';
import { ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

class TestViewContainerRef extends ViewContainerRef {
  get element(): import("@angular/core").ElementRef<any> {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
  get injector(): import("@angular/core").Injector {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
  get parentInjector(): import("@angular/core").Injector {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
  clear(): void {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
  get(index: number): import("@angular/core").ViewRef {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
  get length(): number {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
  createEmbeddedView<C>(templateRef: import("@angular/core").TemplateRef<C>, context?: C, index?: number): import("@angular/core").EmbeddedViewRef<C> {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
  createComponent<C>(componentFactory: import("@angular/core").ComponentFactory<C>, index?: number, injector?: import("@angular/core").Injector, projectableNodes?: any[][], ngModule?: import("@angular/core").NgModuleRef<any>): import("@angular/core").ComponentRef<C> {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
  insert(viewRef: import("@angular/core").ViewRef, index?: number): import("@angular/core").ViewRef {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
  move(viewRef: import("@angular/core").ViewRef, currentIndex: number): import("@angular/core").ViewRef {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
  indexOf(viewRef: import("@angular/core").ViewRef): number {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
  remove(index?: number): void {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
  detach(index?: number): import("@angular/core").ViewRef {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }

}

describe('ModalHostDirective', () => {
  it('should create an instance', () => {
    const directive = new ModalHostDirective(new TestViewContainerRef());
    expect(directive).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Disclaimer: As far as actually writing tests against this TestViewContainerRef, well...I leave that to all of you. But this at least satisfies `ng test`.

Cheers!

Comment: In my case, `viewContainer` is available but `viewContainer.injector` returns `null`, do you know how to resolve this?

Comment: I suppose it depends on how you're trying to use the injector. Are you trying to use it directly?

Comment: This is how I fix the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65355414/angular-10-testing-viewcontainerrefs-injector-returns-undefined

Answer (score 2):

I would let Angular inject the `viewContainerRef` using its normal machinations by using [a test host component](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#component-inside-a-test-host). Normally, I would think that the directive would be detectable using `fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(FooDirective))` (buried in [this part](https://angular.io/guide/testing-attribute-directives#testing-the-highlightdirective) of the guide), but it doesn't seem to be. I [asked Angular why that doesn't work](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/46841). In any case, you can build access to the anchor directive directly in the test host, and that seems to work fine.

The basic pattern:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[fooHost]',
})
class FooDirective {
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {}
}

@Component({
  template: '<ng-template fooHost></ng-template>',
})
class TestHostComponent {
  @ViewChild(FooDirective, { static: true }) fooDirective!: FooDirective;
}
```

Then to access the `viewContainerRef`:

```
it(
   'FooDirective gets viewContainerRef',
   () => {
     const fooDirective = fixture.componentInstance.fooDirective;
     expect(fooDirective.viewContainerRef).toBeDefined();
   }
);
```

See [this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-unit-testing-examples-tpfzzf?file=src/app/demo.cmpnt.spec.ts).

Comment: Thanks, this was very useful! I've used it to mock both `ViewContainerRef` and `ElementRef` which was used in my Directive's constructor. Minor note if anyone else encounters the error `HierarchyRequestError: Node can't be inserted in a #comment parent.`: try changing the `<ng-template>` in the TestHostComponent to an actual element, like `<div>`. Thanks again. :)