# Angular 10 testing ViewContainerRef's injector returns undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

The problem happens after migrating our project from Angular 8.2.14 to Angular 10.2.24.

This is the test code

```js
fdescribe('PopupModalService Testing', () => {
    let componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver;
    let viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef;
    let popupModalService: PopupModalService;

    beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
        const viewContainerRefSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ViewContainerRef', ['insert']);

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                PopupModalComponent,
                DialogApiComponent,
                BrokerFormPopoverComponent,
                BrokerContextMenuComponent
            ],
            imports: [
                ReactiveFormsModule,
                TranslateModule.forRoot()
            ],
            providers: [
                { provide: ViewContainerRef, useValue: viewContainerRefSpy },
                PopupModalService
            ],
            schemas: [
                NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
            ]
        });

        TestBed.overrideModule(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, {
            set: {
                entryComponents: [
                    PopupModalComponent,
                    DialogApiComponent,
                    BrokerFormPopoverComponent,
                    BrokerContextMenuComponent
                ]
            }
        });

        componentFactoryResolver = TestBed.inject(ComponentFactoryResolver);
        viewContainerRef = TestBed.inject(ViewContainerRef);
        popupModalService = new PopupModalService(componentFactoryResolver);
    }));

    it('should create PopupModalComponent', () => {
        expect(popupModalService.create(viewContainerRef, ModalType.SIMPLE, 'Test Title', 'Test Content', PopupActionType.SAVE)).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should create BrokerContextMenuComponent', () => {
        expect(popupModalService.createBrokerContextMenu(viewContainerRef, 999, 999)).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

This is the component's code

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PopupModalService {

    factoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver;

    constructor(@Inject(ComponentFactoryResolver) factoryResolver) {
        this.factoryResolver = factoryResolver;
    }

    create(
        viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
        modalType: ModalType,
        title: string,
        content: string,
        popupActionType?: PopupActionType): PopupModalComponent {

        const factory = this.factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(PopupModalComponent);
        const popupRef = factory.create(viewContainer.injector);
        const popup = popupRef.instance;
        popup.modalType = modalType;
        popup.title = title;
        popup.content = content;
        popup.setComponentRef(popupRef);
        popup.popupActionType = popupActionType;
        popup.hide();
        viewContainer.insert(popupRef.hostView);
        popup.initFormValue();
        return popup;
    }
}
```

After adding some logs to see which part is `undefined`, it's actually the `viewContainer.injector` is the undefined one.

This code did work in past, it only failed to run after the migration.

I've tried

- [Angular Directive ViewContainerRef Test Mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56828097/angular-directive-viewcontainerref-test-mock).
- https://angular2.programmingpedia.net/en/tutorial/831/dynamically-add-components-using-viewcontainerref-createcomponent

Please help to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still can't find the reason one it doesn't work on Angular 10. However, my idea is to replace the `undefined` injector by `TestBed`. I've discovered that `TestBed` is a `Injector` itself.

In the test code, I will change this line from

```js
expect(popupModalService.create(viewContainerRef, ModalType.SIMPLE, 'Test Title', 'Test Content', PopupActionType.SAVE)).toBeDefined();
```

to

```js
expect(popupModalService.create(viewContainerRef, ModalType.SIMPLE, 'Test Title', 'Test Content', PopupActionType.SAVE, TestBed)).toBeDefined();
```

and in the `PopupModalService`, change the `create` method to

```js
    create(
        viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
        modalType: ModalType,
        title: string,
        content: string,
        popupActionType?: PopupActionType,
        injector?: Injector): PopupModalComponent {

        const factory = this.factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(PopupModalComponent);
        const popupRef = factory.create(injector === undefined ? viewContainer.injector : injector);
        const popup = popupRef.instance;
        popup.modalType = modalType;
        popup.title = title;
        popup.content = content;
        popup.setComponentRef(popupRef);
        popup.popupActionType = popupActionType;
        popup.hide();
        viewContainer.insert(popupRef.hostView);
        popup.initFormValue();
        return popup;
    }
```

I make the last param `injector` optional, this will keep the existing code work normally without any changes.

UPDATE: Better yet, we can update only the test code, like this

```js
const viewContainerRefSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ViewContainerRef', ['insert'], {'injector': TestBed});
```

This works the same as above, the benefit is we don't touch the normal code, we only change the test code.